# joomla plugin extension loads css file on every page

Tags: css, joomla, joomla2.5

I'm using a custom plugin extension with Joomla 2.5. This plug-in is targeted for a single page on my site. But for some reason I noticed it loads the css file on every single page.

The code for the plugin loads this css file:

```
$doc->addStyleSheet($pluginAssetsUrl . '/css/aecuserpage.css');
```

I don't assume this is common but I'm not sure about plugins. Can I make it only apply the the page I want instead of every single page. Any thoughts on how to debug this would be appreciated.

The plugin prints a simple table on an article page and uses the plugin function `onContentPrepare`

Comment: What is the plugin doing? For example if it's targeting a specific class/id you could search for the class/id and if it exists then include the css file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use these snippets to manage your problem:

1) Load CSS by checking the active menu item

```
$menu = &JSite::getMenu();
$menuItem = $menu->getActive();
$Itemid = $menuItem->id;
if($Itemid!=1)
{
 $doc->addStyleSheet($pluginAssetsUrl . '/css/aecuserpage.css');
}
```

2)Load CSS upon component

```
if (JRequest::getCmd( 'option' ) == 'com_k2'){
        $doc->addStyleSheet($pluginAssetsUrl . '/css/aecuserpage.css');
}
```

3)Load CSS only in home page

```
<?php if(JRequest::getInt('Itemid') == $menu->getDefault()) {
   $doc->addStyleSheet($pluginAssetsUrl . '/css/aecuserpage.css');
}?>
```

4)Load CSS upon active menu id

```
<?php
$menuID = JSite::getMenu()->getActive()->id ;
  if ($menuID == '6')
  {
   $doc->addStyleSheet($pluginAssetsUrl . '/css/aecuserpage.css');
  }
?>
```

5)Load CSS upon active language:

```
$lang =& JFactory::getLanguage();
switch ($lang) {
case 'en-gb':
$doc->addStyleSheet($pluginAssetsUrl . '/css/aecuserpage.css');
break;
}
```

6)Load CSS upon users

```
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
if($user->get('id')==0){
//user is logged in
 $doc->addStyleSheet($pluginAssetsUrl . '/css/aecuserpage.css');
}
```

7)Load CSS upon URL

```
$u =& JFactory::getURI();
if($u=="http://www.example.com/joomla/index.php?task=view&id=12&Itemid=29")
{
$doc->addStyleSheet($pluginAssetsUrl . '/css/aecuserpage.css');
}
```

Comment: Aha! #1 did it. Props to @Lodder as he was close. Great list of options btw! Thanks.

Comment: Gracias mate, glad that I was able to help

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like the following:

```
$application = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $application->getMenu();
$item = $menu->getItem(1);
if ($item == 1){
    $doc = JFactory::getDocument(); //Remove it you already have this line
    $doc->addStyleSheet($pluginAssetsUrl . '/css/aecuserpage.css');
}
```

Change the number "1" to whatever menu item the page belongs to.

Please note I haven't tested this so let me know if it works. If it doesn't, I'll see what i can dig up.

Comment: Close, thanks. This code definitely stops it from mostly loading (oddly it still shows up on the root of the site). I'm playing around with the menu item id as it also doesn't now work on the page I want it to work with...sigh. I'll research more if `getMenu` or `getItem` are doing what they are supposed to.

Comment: Tried everything, with no luck. Tried `getItems('menutype','mymenu')` which at least returns something. `getItem` does not. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that getting `Itemid` inside `plugin` will work. I have a suggestion that you move the css code in template index.php and check the itemid condition it'll work there.

Answer (score 0):

What event is the plugin responding to? What group is it in? For many events you can check the $context of the page.  If you know that it will only load on a certain page use those identifiers.

e.g. here is a line from the pagination plugin:

if ($params->get('show_item_navigation') && ($context == 'com_content.article') && ($view == 'article')) {

or this from loadmodule

```
    $canProceed = $context == 'com_content.article';
    if (!$canProceed) {
        return;
    }
```

Comment: The event is: `onContentPrepare`

Comment: Right so that happens on every single page. So what you want to do is do an if ($context != whatever) {return;} look at some of the other content plugins you will see that basically you are checking the url.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the "whatever" part is? Other plugins have some stuff as you put in your answer but I'm not sure what they mean. For example loadmodule I have no idea what `com_content.article` is.

Comment: The url for an article would be index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=2  (for article 2).  In other words that is asking what is in the url and if the url does not indicate that we are in an article then don't continue with running the plugin.

Comment: Okay, getting there. If I do the same as loadmodule it does only load for articles. But now to be more specific how would I specify article id 30 for example?

Comment: Get the id from the request using jinput (assuming you can't just add it to the context com_content.article.30.